# SQL Server State: 42000-5074 and SQL State: 42000-4922

Tags: sql-server, uppercase

I am encountering an app issue after I manually updated all the columns to UPPER CASE.

> Error: SQL State: 42000-5074
>   Message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]
>   The index 'OBJECTREVM14F63D20A' is dependent on
>   column 'FILE_NAME'.
>
> Error: SQL State: 42000-4922
>   Message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN FILE_NAME failed because one or
>   more objects access this column.

What does it mean? There was only one app running on the database so I am totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

You have an index that uses the columns. SQL Server doesn't allow changes to columns that have indexes or constraints on them

The name is in the message: sse SSMS Object Explorer to find this index

> The index 'OBJECTREVM14F63D20A' ...

Or use

```
sp_help 'Mytable'
```